# FTSearch that looks for '-'

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

does anybody know if there is a possibility to search for '-' using FTSearch?

```
Set col = db.ftsearch({ [services] = "-"}, 0)
```

dat requests does not work and instead says:

> Notes error: Full text error; see log for more information (
>   [services] = "-")

Comment: That character is definitely not in index, so I expect it as slow as db.search()...

Comment: This ftsearch is correct and should return a result. What does log say? Too many results?

Comment: the message I shown is from log 07-10-2013 11:51:42   GTR search error for "D:\Domino\data\databaseft\ftgi": Work area overflown due to many hits. Error-Number = 299: Full text error; see log for more information

Comment: So, too many results like I guessed. Try it with parameter 100 instead of 0 just for test purposes.

Comment: does not work with parameter 2, 100 or any another number. and f.x. I tried to searcg for "--" and it worked well, but this "-" does not work.

Comment: Maybe it won't work at all for large databases: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/4d21f120f5a2cf4985256a150076d0d5/8c56550338d30b618525730d003ee7c7?OpenDocument - it worked for my example database though.

Comment: http://dpastov.blogspot.sk/2008/11/i-was-facing-with-strange-error-last.html seems you blogged about it 5 years ago. And there is pretty old SPR about it - regress? - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=sim483cc2fb70a81f43785256a800073b35f

Comment: right, last time I solved problem by simply avoiding such requests, but it was not a solution but just workaround

Comment: I tried your code again with a larger database (4 G and 70,000 docs) on client and server all Windows 7 and 8.5.3 - works perfect without problems. What is your version/system?

Comment: mine is Domino 8.5.3 and Windows. Definitely I do not understand something in Domino FTSearch :) anyway thanks you all for such good discussion. I'm satisfied.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann I have tested it '[subject] contains "-"' on my mail file with 12k docs and it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The full text search treats most symbol characters as a white space. The exception is if the search term itself is wrapped in quotes.

The FT search engine also uses [3-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) for searching. This means that less then 3 characters will not return the results you expect. White spaces would be treated in that search, but only in the context of the found text.

For example:  "ce " would find "space " but not "space." or "space" or "spaced".

If you are looking for the field that only contains "-", then a better solution is to create a view with a column containing that field value, and/or filter by that field being that value.

Comment: where can I find a list with characters are considered as symbol character?

Comment: How can I find it if I can't search on it. ;)  There is syntax symbols listed here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/full-text-syntax But there may be a few more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do a full text search in a view? You probably would get better response time and less server impact to use @Formula language if you are working with a view.

I try to keep away on doing full text searches on the entire database. You can use a search on a view collection for faster results. There is no restriction on how many views you can have in a db. There is a cost for everything though. There are so many little tricks that can be used to get better results. Please give us more details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: it is obviously from line I put that it is Database.FTSeach
and I've no clue what details do u expect, it is simply Database.FTSeach